# Query name/Help Text/Description of custom fields in a custom object

Tags: apex, custom-object, custom-field, sobject

I want to Query `Name`/`Help Text`/`Description` of custom fields in a custom object. Something like:

```
SELECT Name, HelpText, Description FROM sboject WHERE object = XXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such attribute on an `SObject` as `InlineHelpText`. If you want to get the `Description` for a particular object, you must use the `Metadata API`. You would think you could get it using describes, but you would be wrong. That attribute is curiously missing from the `DescribeSObjectResult` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm).

Before using this code, you must install the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://githubsfdeploy.herokuapp.com/?owner=financialforcedev&repo=apex-mdapi) and  set up its `Remote Site Settings`. Then you can do:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomObject customObject = (MetadataService.CustomObject)service.readMetadata(
    'CustomObject', new List<String>{'MyObject__c'}
).getRecords()[0];
system.debug(customObject.description);
```

---

As for specific fields, you can see a similar conclusion about the `Description` for a field posted years ago here:

[How to get a field's description via API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/how-to-get-a-fields-description-via-api)

However, as noted there, you can get the `InlineHelpText` of a field simply from its describe:

```
String helpText = MyObject__c.MyField__c.getDescribe().getInlineHelpText();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Tooling API and you can use the below query to get Custom Field Metadata including Help Text:

```
SELECT Id, EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName, DeveloperName, RelationshipLabel, Description, InlineHelpText, DefaultValue, CreatedDate, LastModifiedDate, Length, Precision, Scale, SummaryOperation, TableEnumOrId
FROM CustomField
Where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN ('Account', 'Lead', 'Contact', 'Opportunity', 'User', 'Asset', 'Launch__c', 'Campaign')
```